# iOS firebase uncaught Exception

Tags: ios, firebase

After registering Firebase to the app, an error occurred while building

My Code

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore


class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}
@main
struct TestTabBarApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message

> `com.firebase.installations`. Reason: The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized. One way to ensure this is to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the App  Delegate's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI)..

i try this in TestTabBarApp

```
init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
```

but I get the same error What's the problem? Even search for them, They're different cases